# window trigger doesn't return the most updated result

Tags: java, apache-flink, flink-streaming

I'm trying to measure the latency of a Flink application which have a window operation as shown below:

```
SingleOutputStreamOperator<String> branch = stream
                .getSideOutput(outputTag2)
                .keyBy(MetricObject::getRootAssetId)
                .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(60)))
                .trigger(ContinuousEventTimeTrigger.of(Time.seconds(15)))
                .aggregate(new CountDistinctAggregate(), new CountDistinctProcess())
                .name("windowed-count-distinct")
                .uid("windowed-count-distinct")
                .map((value)->String.valueOf(value.getTimestamp().toEpochMilli()))
                .name("send-timestamp");
```

I'm considering event time and to extract timestamp I use this watermark strategy:

```
                        .<SingleRecord>forBoundedOutOfOrderness(Duration.ofSeconds(15))
                        .withTimestampAssigner((event, timestamp) -> event.getTimestamp().toEpochMilli()))
```

The aggregation function saves a particular object as an accumulator containing also the timestamp extracted; these timestamps are written in a kafka topic. The problem is that the timestamps returned are these:

```
1639651859988
1639651890163
1639651904900
1639651919728
1639651919728
1639651949973
1639651965085
1639651979870
```

the timestamps returned aren't equally spaced as I was expecting, and the fourth and fifth are equal but they have been returned spaced by 15 seconds and this isn't possible because the input of the application records are continuously generated every second (10 per second). In other tests I obtained also worse situations like this:

```
1639651979870
1639651992771
1639651992771
1639651992771
1639651992771
1639652189791
1639652205001
1639652219876
```

the curious fact is that, when I use a simple tumbling window without trigger:

```
 .window(TumblingEventTimeWindows.of(Time.seconds(15)))
```

the timestamps returned are equally spaced as expected:

```
1639652429766
1639652444930
1639652459900
1639652474609
1639652489746
1639652504862
1639652519734
1639652534847
```

I really don't understand which is the problem, it seems like the accumulators in the aggregation function doesn't upgrade properly.

Answer (score 0):

I think you could check the input data to Flink streaming to verify whether the result is what you expect.

For the first streaming, the aggregate operation runs 4 times(every 15 sec) over the data set of 60 seconds' window. Not sure your logic in the aggregation. E.g. assuming we have a window of 3 sec, and the trigger is every 1 sec. The operator is to get the max element in the window. Also assuming the input is generated every 1 sec. If the input is 1, 3, 2, ..., then we will see output like 1, 3, 3... from Flink as the first window has [1, 3, 2] in its pane, and for each trigger to get max element, the result will be 1, 3, 3.

For the second streaming job, each window has one trigger time, so e.g. using the input from above as an example, if the window is for 1 sec, we will get 1, 3, 2, ...